# How to fix syntax error at or near "psql"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having this error with postgresql here is my code:

```sql
psql -c "COPY (SELECT
  u.id,
  u.email_id,
  u.iam_user_id
FROM
  public."user" u
WHERE
  u.user_type like 'guest') TO STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" -h user.postgresql.business.private -d user -U dev-user > /home/delete_guest_users.csv;
```

Comment: ___UPDATE___
I fixed it... I was inside the table 'user' not actually in the postgresql DB REPL!

Comment: I guess psql is a command line tool. and it can just be a typo of single/double qutoes of command vs. query. also I don't remember if you can remove your post, but if possible try removing as it does not seem to provide valuable info.